# Calculate height of water column to keep tank with fixed drain rate constantly filled?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, fluid, flow-control

I would like to know how to calculate the height of a water source connected with a 1/2 inch hose to a tank that is constantly draining @600L/H, such that the tank would never empty, i.e, the rate of fill through the water column by gravity should be 600L/H. I did my own calculation but mine produced results so happy and convergent to my application that I'd like to be sure. Thanks.

applying v^2 = u^2 + 2as (the third equation of motion) to the problem where v is the final velocity, u is the initial velocity assumed at 0, a would be acceleration due to gravity (g=9.81m/s^2) and s is displacement.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apart from fluid type and pipe thickness, flow rates heavily depend on the pipe material, inflow and outflow geometry, pipe/tube geometry, along some other factors. With all those factors known, you could make a calculation using standard fluid mechanics, but those calculations will never be exact. Fluid mechanics are notorious for being very unpredictable, and small changes can heavily influence the real result. (Especially when you get into 'turbulent' regions.)

Your own calculation gives you a rough estimate on how large you would need the water column to be for your particular situation. The best thing to do now is use that estimate and make a setup to test how large your water column needs to be.

Keep in mind though that your water column will also need some sort of inflow to keep it at a constant level, if you want the constant waterflow of 600L/h.

I don't know your exact setup/situation, but my gut says that it would be better to have some sort of flow measurement connected to a control valve that together can set the flow at 600L/h. This would make changing water levels in your supply vat less of a concern.

Comment: I appreciate your engineer's depth of the concept concerns, but I think we do not need to overthink this into pipe materials and pipe thickness etc. I am using a regular PVC pipe, and I do not expect an ideal flow as I do not expect my pump to give out the ideal 600L/H (its definitely lower, but I do not need to know that). My set up has valves which would not let my tank over flow even if the flow into the tank is faster than the flow out of the tank. The fluid would be water, so consider the math that I have done till now. 600L/H (which is the least rate needed) means 0.0001666667 m3/s.

Comment: 1/2 inch pvc pipe has cross sectional area of 0.00012667686 m2. That means the water would need to flow through it @1.31m/s for a flow rate of 6L/H

Comment: using v2 - u2 = 2as, where u = 0 and a = g and v = 1.31m/s, s comes out to 0.088 m

Comment: so if I have the source (doesn't matter if it completely empties at some point) at a height of 8cm above the tank, I should be able to achieve the flow rate desired, doesn't matter if the source is just a bottle of water or the entire Indian ocean in an ocean sized bucket.

Comment: does that sound like meaningful to you?

Comment: Have added a sketch to my question.

Comment: @DribbleNibble, you calculate it like the answer says.  Your specification is "such that the tank will never empty," which isn't very good for an engineering spec.  FLow rates are determined by pipe geometry.  If you want to eyeball it, an engineering forum probably isn't the place for the question.

Comment: @DribbleNibble I'm not sure on your calculations, specifically I'm not sure what you mean with "v2 - u2 = 2as". It might be good to add these calculations in your question (using math-formatting and stating each variable meaning clearly). You don't seem to incorporate flow resistance in your formula anywhere, which is absolutely key. If by your statement about a bottle/ocean you mean that the area of your source does not matter, only the water height above the source's outlet, then you would be correct.

Comment: @Chris_abc check my question, have given more elaborations on the equation. Flow resistance doesn't bother me as I can easily compensate it by placing the source at a significantly higher level (like a meter almost) above the tank and I am also not expecting the tank to be emptied at the ideal rated 600L/H of the pump pumping out of it.

Comment: "Flow resistance doesn't bother me as I can easily compensate it by placing the source at a significantly higher level (like a meter almost)" It does not work like that. And your equation of motion formula is not what is used for pipe flow. Look up "bernoulli's principle" and make sure you understand it if you want to make a real calculation for this scenario. If you're able to change your setup as easily as you say, just conduct an experiment and see for yourself what you need.